# Not able to connect HP ALM through QTP connection

Tags: hp-quality-center

[image]

Not able to connect HP ALM through QTP connection
screen shot attached

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the ALM client on the machine where you are trying to connect to ALM from UFT? Regardless, I believe that connecting and downloading ALM components through UFT requires administrative privileges on the client. Have you tried to run UFT as administrator and then connect to ALM?

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was, @sakshi?